# Finding a non match in two arrays and adding non match to last position in column

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to find the non match in several columns by using two arrays in excel VBA

So the code is using in Column A(varr array) in "Sammanställning" sheet as a kind on Facit for the other array arr(column k from other sheets) to find the non match and then add the non match last in the A column in "Sammanställning" sheet.

Now for the problem:

It works but only kind of. It does the matches, finds a non match adds it to the end in the right place.
But after the first sheet if it adds a non match it doesn't update the varr array.
I tried to update the array using the 3 variations below but non worked. I got "out of index" error.

```
ReDim Preserve varr(LBound(varr) To (UBound(varr) + 1)) As Variant
ReDim Preserve varr(LBound(varr) To (UBound(varr) + 1))
ReDim Preserve varr(UBound(varr) + 1)
```

The first part is so that I don't look in the wrong sheets, i use GlobalSheetName for this.

```
 Sub KollaFlyttaData()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim ShName As String
 Dim char As Variant
 Dim blnChar As Boolean
 Dim Sistaraden As Variant
 Dim varr As Variant
 varr = Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each char In Split(GlobalSheetName, ",")
            If ws.Name = char Then
              blnChar = True
              Exit For
            Else
              blnChar = False
            End If
        Next
        If Not blnChar = True Then
                ws.Activate
                    Dim arr As Variant
                    arr = Range("K3:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).Value
                    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, match As Boolean
                    For Each x In arr
                        match = False
                        For Each y In varr
                            If x = y Then match = True
                        Next y
                            If Not match Then
                                Sistaraden = Sheets("Sammanställning").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                                Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("A" & Sistaraden).Value = x
                                ReDim Preserve varr(LBound(varr) To (UBound(varr) + 1)) As Variant
                            End If
                            Next x
                End If
      Next
    End Sub
```

How can I update varr so I can add all the non match and add the non match to after the last non empty cell in A column in "Sammanställning" sheet.

Comment: When you do `varr = Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("A1:A" ... ` it's a *snapshot* of the `Values` from the range.  If you later update the range, you will need to do `varr = ...` again (instead of `redim varr ... `)

Comment: I did a `varr=...` but only got it to ad more new cells with data that already was in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a dictionary instead? You could tie this to a button push or worksheet events (possibly the first easier) in order to update going forwards.

I am avoiding, for now, your code to get the correct sheet and simply demonstrating the dictionary part:

```
Option Explicit

Sub KollaFlyttaData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim varr()
    With Sheets("Sammanställning")
        varr = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim currValue As Long

    For currValue = LBound(varr, 1) To UBound(varr, 1)
        If Not dict.exists(varr(currValue, 1)) And Len(varr(currValue, 1)) > 0 Then
            dict.Add varr(currValue, 1), varr(currValue, 1)
        End If
    Next currValue

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws

            Dim arr()
            arr = .Range("K3:K" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).Value

            For currValue = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

             If Not dict.exists(arr(currValue, 1)) And Len(arr(currValue, 1)) > 0 Then
                dict.Add arr(currValue, 1), arr(currValue, 1)
             End If

            Next currValue

        End With

    Next ws

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this to see if worked? And does it need any further explanation?

Comment: I cant get it to work fully, it ads one but overwrites the other before the one its add. So if you got 4 new items you overwrite the 3 last items in the original list.

Comment: Hummmmm....I may see if I still have the workbook so we can work out what the differences are between our sets of data. It worked for me so maybe I have misunderstood something about your data.

Comment: Did the workbook help to illustrate how the dict worked?

Comment: Yes it did, but it didn't solve the problem. When trying to exclude some sheets it still looks in them and extract the info from K column.

Comment: i used

 `For Each char In Split(GlobalSheetName, ",")
            If ws.Name = char Then
              blnChar = True
              Exit For
            Else
              blnChar = False
            End If
        Next
        If Not blnChar = True Then`
after that i went in to the code from `With ws`